# Flutter bottomNavigationBar, how to make my customClipper to not occlude the body content

Tags: flutter, bottom-navigation-bar, flutter-clippath, customclipper

I've implemented this bottomNavigationBar using a custom clipper. The issue is with the scaffold body.

[image]

I wish the body content to be visible from this area of the bottomNavigationBar instead of being occluded by the gray zone.

[image]

Do you happen to know if there is a scaffold setup to achieve this? Otherway I might need to come up with a different layout within the body section.

Comment: You can try with `ClipPath` or you can provide `shape` on `BottomAppBar`

Comment: maybe sharing ur code would do better

Comment: @Md.YeasinSheikh I set the same path to the NotchedShape and after creating the floating button, the navigation bottom bar still have a different color background which occludes the body content

Comment: @JBJason Shared it, for the most part the general context

Comment: @MiguelG try without SafeArea ()  or maybe without SafeArea() & shrinkwrap too

Comment: Please [don’t post images of code, error messages, or other textual data.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Answer (score 0):

**Yes, it's a common problem.**

as long as you have used a `Container` and made some `clipping` customization for it, to appear looks like a `BottomNavigationBar`. it will but stills a container that have a clip path to be rendered.

The problem occurs **when you realize that, the other part of the container you have clipped still exist**, *it hides any widget that get behind (Your problem).*

> it's an advantage over another, good shape but hides the content
> behind.

So, i recommend the use of `BottomAppBar` and give it a `CircularNotchedRectangle` as a `shape`.

Comment: I shared the code structure. As explained in main post it consisted of a bottomNavigationBar and a body content filled with sliver widgets. 

Indeed, originally I was looking for a setup that can make it work using the bottomNavigationBar so I do not spend a good amount of time doing modifications. But it seems that we agree on stacking a custom nav bar widget within the same scaffold body to build this layout.